# nftables error when jumping to `output` chain

Tags: iptables, nftables

I trying to `migrate` from `iptables` script to `nftables`. In this script I want to `redirect` some outgoing tcp/udp traffic to local proxy excluding some subnets. `iptables` script works `as expected` (ip's are changed):

```bash
iptables -t nat -N PROXY

iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d 1.1.1.1/32 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -d 1.0.0.1/32 -j RETURN

iptables -t nat -A PROXY -p tcp -d 1.0.0.0/8 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3127
iptables -t nat -A PROXY -p udp -d 1.0.0.0/8 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3127

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 1.0.0.0/8 -j PROXY
```

But adapted `nftables` script gives an `error`:

```bash
Error: Could not process rule: Operation not supported
add rule nat OUTPUT ip daddr { 1.0.0.0/8 } ip protocol { tcp, udp } jump PROXY
                                                                         ^^^^^
```

Here is `nftables` script I want to adapt:

```bash
nft add table nat

nft add chain nat PROXY { type nat hook prerouting priority -1\; }
nft add chain nat OUTPUT { type nat hook output priority -1\; }

nft add rule nat PROXY ip daddr { 1.1.1.1/32, 1.0.0.1/32 } return
nft add rule nat PROXY ip daddr { 1.0.0.0/8 } ip protocol { tcp, udp } redirect to :3127

nft add rule nat OUTPUT ip daddr { 1.0.0.0/8 } ip protocol { tcp, udp } jump PROXY
```

Some notes:

- all tables/chains/ruleset are flushed/deleted before running each script
- running `lsmod | grep ^nf` shows all kernel modules are loaded (afaik)
- everything is executed by root

Thank you.

EDIT:

`nft list ruleset` gives this result:

```
table ip nat {
        chain PROXY {
                type nat hook prerouting priority filter - 1; policy accept;
                ip daddr { 1.0.0.1, 1.1.1.1 } return
                ip daddr 1.0.0.0/8 ip protocol { tcp, udp } redirect to :3127
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type nat hook output priority filter - 1; policy accept;
        }
}
```

The last rule is not appended because of error.

`uname -a`: Linux honeypot 6.1.7-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jan 18 22:33:03 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Could you please give us the output of `nft list ruleset`? And what OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the NFTables configuration you have the line `nft add chain nat PROXY { type nat hook prerouting priority -1\; }` which includes a prerouting hook which I can not find in your IPTables configuration (`iptables -t nat -N PROXY`).

Because there is a hook it is not possible to make a jump to it.

This configuration without the hook should work:

```
nft add table nat

nft add chain nat PROXY
nft add chain nat OUTPUT { type nat hook output priority -1\; }

nft add rule nat PROXY ip daddr { 1.1.1.1/32, 1.0.0.1/32 } return
nft add rule nat PROXY ip daddr { 1.0.0.0/8 } ip protocol { tcp, udp } redirect to :3127

nft add rule nat OUTPUT ip daddr { 1.0.0.0/8 } ip protocol { tcp, udp } jump PROXY
```

---

As you are migrating from IPTables to NFTables I would strongly advice to take a look at the [Atomic rule replacement](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Atomic_rule_replacement) and the [native scripting environment](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Scripting) (/etc/nftables.conf) NFTables offers.